# Using nested for loops to generate primes

Tags: python, algorithm, numbers, primes, primality-test

I created a primality test algorithm, but it doesn't work.

In essence, these are the steps my program takes:

- Ask the user for a lower and upper bound in which to look for primes
- An array, primes, will store my primes
- A nested for loop; the first `for loop` takes every number between the user's lower and upper bounds and then checks if every one of those numbers is divisible by any of the numbers between 2 and the user's upper bound
- If any number between the lower and upper bounds is divisible by any number between 2 and the user's upper bound, the number is obviously not prime.
- Otherwise, the number is appended to the array primes:

```
lower = int(input("Lower Bound: "))
upper = int(input("Upper Bound: "))

print ("Primes between " + str(lower) + " and " + str(upper) + ": ")

primes = []

for i in range (lower, upper): 
  for num in range (2, upper/2):
    if i % num == 0: 
      print (str(i-(lower-1)) + ". " + str(i) + " = No")
      break
  else: 
    primes.append(i)

print(primes)
```

However, the regardless whether a number is prime or not, the function always outputs no, but I have no idea why!

Comment: For your second loop you should only need to go to upper/2. The lowest multiplier you could get would be 2. 2x=n see `for num in range (2, int(upper/2)):`

Comment: You should use `i` in the second loop range.

Comment: @BillSkiCO Yup; that was it. What a silly mistake

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Isn't it interchangeable?

Comment: The inner loop is testing if `i` is prime and `i != upper`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Sorry, I don't understand; `for i in range (lower, upper)` are the numbers being tested against all the divisors in `for num in range (2, upper/2)`. So what do you mean by the inner loop and `i != upper`? Thanks

Comment: @BillSkiCO for the second loop it's enough to go as high as `sqrt(i)`, saving a lot of time for the large numbers. And there's no point testing against even numbers, only the odd numbers, thus making things twice as fast.

Comment: @lenik true, I was assuming since they are using 2 for loops to get a prime and not recursive calling with lru_cache decorator, that importing math to use math.sqrt() wasn’t being allowed for the homework or whatever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it. First, I did the floor division `//` operator so it returns an integer. Also, I made a condition that the divisor couldn't be divided by itself. Because otherwise 4 would be a prime of 4.

```py
lower = int(input("Lower Bound: "))
upper = int(input("Upper Bound: "))

print ("Primes between " + str(lower) + " and " + str(upper) + ": ")

primes = []

for i in range (lower, upper):
  for num in range (2, upper//2):
    if i % num == 0 and num != i: # modification here
      print (str(i-(lower-1)) + ". " + str(i) + " = No")
      break
  else:
    primes.append(i)

print(primes)
```

`Out[1]: [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43]`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I actually made those changes over the past hour, and finally realized each of my mistakes.

Comment: @DarkRunner `for num in range (2, upper//2)` should be `for num in range (2, sqrt(i))`